# How can I set Eclipse Code Formatter to show one array element per line?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

for example, instead of this

```
private weka.classifiers.Classifier[] wekaClassfiers = new weka.classifiers.Classifier[] { new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes(),
        new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial(), new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable(), new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesUpdateable(),
        new weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic(), new weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron(), new weka.classifiers.lazy.LWL(),
```

format like this

```
private weka.classifiers.Classifier[] wekaClassfiers = new weka.classifiers.Classifier[] { 
    new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes(),
    new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomial(), 
    new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesMultinomialUpdateable(), 
    new weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayesUpdateable(),
    new weka.classifiers.functions.Logistic(), 
    new weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron(), 
    new weka.classifiers.lazy.LWL(),
```

Comment: So you are telling that you can do it manually, but formatting code makes it appears as code-snippet-1. You want to know how to make code formatting appears as code-snippet-2?

Comment: exactly. I'd like it like snippet #2 but eclipse default format messed up, making it look like snippet #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's good to look at every preference, tool, or option that's available to you.

From the **Java**->**Code Style**->**Formatter** preference page, create a **New** profile (you're not allowed to modify the ones that are included), and make sure you change the array initializer line wrapping option to be as shown (or another that puts every element on a new line):

[image: Java Code Formatter profile editor dialog]